# Custom RecyclerView is null when passing adapter

Tags: java, android

i'm new to android, but i'm struggling while trying to make work this recycler view.

This is my activity oncreate:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_list);
    backToSft = findViewById(R.id.backToSft);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RetrofitInterface.API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    pref = getSharedPreferences("user_details", MODE_PRIVATE);

    sft = getSharedPreferences("curr_sft", MODE_PRIVATE);
    tagId = sft.getInt("sftId", -1);
    sftName = findViewById(R.id.sftTextName);
    checkListRecycler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerCheckList);
    checkListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    if (tagId > 0) {
        sftName.setText(sft.getString("sftTag", "n/d"));
        getCheckData();
    }
}
```

This is my getCheckData() func:

```
    private void getCheckData() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
        auth += pref.getString("token", null);
        RetrofitInterface service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
        int roleId = pref.getInt("roleId", -1);
        Log.d("ROLE","Is quality oeprator?"+(roleId == UserRole.QUALITY_OPERATOR));
        Call<List<ShortFactoryTagCheck>> call = service.getSFTChecks(tagId, (roleId == UserRole.QUALITY_OPERATOR), auth);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ShortFactoryTagCheck>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ShortFactoryTagCheck>> call, Response<List<ShortFactoryTagCheck>> response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                try {
                    tagChecks = response.body();
                    if (tagChecks.size() > 0) {
                        Log.d("SFT_OBJ","is SFT Obj NULL? "+(checkListRecycler ==null));
                        
                        adapter = new CheckListRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),tagChecks);
                        adapter.setClickListener(new CheckListRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                Object o = adapter.getItem(position);
                                ShortFactoryTagCheck str = (ShortFactoryTagCheck) o; //As you are using Default String Adapter
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sft.edit();
                                editor.putInt("sftCheckId",str.getId());
                                editor.commit();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QualityCheckActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        checkListRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);


                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SftDetailActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("SFT_GSON_ERROR", e.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ShortFactoryTagCheck>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR_SFT_DETAIL", "Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
activity_check_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/aptivDark"
tools:context=".CheckListActivity">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:translationY="-10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/aptivOrange"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateTint="@color/aptivDark"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sftTextName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sftTextName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerCheckList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backToSft"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_button_danger"
    android:onClick="goToSftDetail"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerCheckList" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I open this activity, it gives me NullPointerException on `checkListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));`

I've also tried to clean and rebuild the project, but nothing changed... Also added dependencies to gradle, but still gets error.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Error log

```
2020-10-13 16:22:32.203 5116-5116/com.aptiv.qdc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aptiv.qdc, PID: 5116
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aptiv.qdc/com.aptiv.qdc.CheckListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
    at com.aptiv.qdc.CheckListActivity.onCreate(CheckListActivity.java:66)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7034)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7025)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: is checkListRecycler RecyclerView variable ? and I think you should cast to RecyclerView like (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sftTextName)

Comment: @andika_kurniawan yes it's a RecyclerView variable

Comment: show your XML file `R.layout.activity_check_list` (edit question, put in there)

Comment: @snachmsm added xml code in question under EDIT

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the correct androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView library?

Comment: @LucaPizzini i've imported this two lines in build.gradle: `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'` `implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc03"`

Comment: The library in the gradle file looks ok. I was referring at the import section, at the top of the .java file, where you import all the libraries used in the file.

Comment: @LucaPizzini So in the java file I've imported `import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;`, is it correct? I'm running API level 28 (android 8.1)

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Can you post the full error log?

Comment: @LucaPizzini added error log in edit

Comment: @LukeSmith can you debug and check if other findViewById calls return null or an object?

Comment: @barkatme `2020-10-13 16:40:38.602 9642-9642/com.aptiv.qdc D/SFT_OBJ: is SFT Obj NULL? true` yes it is

Comment: idk realy what to look for else, but is onCreate method annotated with @Override? ☺

Comment: is `findViewById` returning null for any of the other views?

Comment: below `backToSft = findViewById(R.id.backToSft);` line put `backToSft.setVisibility(View.GONE);` - is it also null? maybe there is a chance you have multiple `R.layout.activity_check_list` files in different density buckets

Comment: @snachmsm yes you were correct, because android studio decided to create 2 versions of the same xml, one for the v21 and one for the current version of API... I've added the recycler view to the v21 xml file and it works... shame on me...

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, feel free to upvote/accept :) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below `backToSft = findViewById(R.id.backToSft);` line put `backToSft.setVisibility(View.GONE);` - is it also null? maybe there is a chance you have multiple `R.layout.activity_check_list` files in different density buckets

(copy of comment)

Answer (score 0):

is `checkListRecycler` RecyclerView variable ? and I think you should cast to
RecyclerView like

```
(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.sftTextName)
```

And change `checkListRecycler variable to RecyclerView`

Comment: I've casted it but I still getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aptiv.qdc/com.aptiv.qdc.CheckListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @LukeSmith try to change applicationContext to activity / ordinary context

Comment: Changed to `checkListRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));` but the error persists...